# Python dunders __copy__ e __deepcopy__

Tags: python, python-3.x

Já vi em alguns códigos, principalmente no Django os `dunders` `__copy__` e `__deepcopy__`, a idéia por traś deles eu entendo que fornecer cópias do objeto, mas normalmente os `dunders` podem ser chamados de forma digamos `"especial"` alguns exemplos seriam o `len() invoca __len__`, `== invoca __eq__` minha pergunta é esses dunders possuem uma forma `"especial"` de serem invocados?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eles são invocados, mas não diretamente pelo runtime da linguagem, e sim, pelas funçes `copy` e `deepcopy` do módulo `copy`  da biblioteca pedrão:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

No final da documentação é explicado:

> In order for a class to define its own copy implementation, it can
>   define special methods `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()`. The former is
>   called to implement the shallow copy operation; no additional
>   arguments are passed. The latter is called to implement the deep copy
>   operation; it is passed one argument, the memo dictionary. If the
>   `__deepcopy__()` implementation needs to make a deep copy of a component, it should call the deepcopy() function with the component
>   as first argument and the memo dictionary as second argument.

Traduzindo:

> "Para uma classe definir sua própria implementação de cópia, ela pode
>   definir os métodos especiais `__copy__()` e `__deepcopy__()`. O
>   primeiro é chamado para a operação de cópia raza; nenhum argumento
>   adicional é passado. O último é chamado para implementar a operação de
>   cópia profunda; é passado um argumento, o dicionário de "memo". Se a
>   implementação de `__deepcopy__()` precisar efetuar uma cópia profunda
>   de algum outro componente, ela deve chamar a função  `deepcopy()`  com
>   o componente como primeirio e o dicionário de "memo" como segundo
>   argumento"

Não é *obrigatório* que qualquer sistema ou base de código use o `copy.copy` da biblioteca padrão para copiar seus próprios objetos, mas se ela o fizer, o protocolo já está definido - e se todo mundo usar, por conta desse protocolo, as cópias vão funcionar bem.  Se você tentar usar
o django, e copiar um objeto instanciado sem usar o `copy.copy` pode ter problemas por não passar pelos métodos especiais definidos nos objetos.

Ah, só pra demonstrar as chamadas, no terminal do ipython dá pra fazer:

```
In [19]: from copy import copy, deepcopy

In [20]: class Teste:
    ...:     def __copy__(self):
    ...:         print("copy")
    ...:         return Teste()
    ...:     def __deepcopy__(self, memo=None):
    ...:         print("deepcopy")
    ...:         return Teste()
    ...:     

In [21]: copy(Teste())
copy
Out[21]: <__main__.Teste at 0x7f6c19e97fd0>

In [22]: deepcopy(Teste())
deepcopy
Out[22]: <__main__.Teste at 0x7f6c19e99e48>
```

Comment: Mais uma vez excelente explicação. Obrigado jsbueno.